# How to retopologize an artifact?

Tags: sculpting, retopology, resolution, vr

I got the job with my team that we need to do a VR mobile app that lets the users look at the scanned versions of artifacts in it. We got a scanner and the artifacts themselves. Here is one model I already got:

[image]
[image]
[image]

As you can see it is really complex and irregularly shaped. To be used in the app, I would need to retopologize it but because of the irregular shape and mostly because I got really little time to do it (it should actually be done by now), I don't have the time to do it by hand. I think it's important to note that no artifacts will be animated of course.

What method, what modifiers should I use to make it lower resolution?

Comment: I'm not sure there's anything as good as manual retopology, but you could try a remesh, then bake the normals from the high-poly version onto the remeshed or retopologized version in order to keep all the details?

Comment: This might be interesting to look at: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/retopology.html

Comment: Remeshing ends up with terrible deformations to the original mesh unfortunately. What about the decimate modifier? I just tried it now and looks almost identical but I am not sure if this is the way to do this. I am mostly curious about if there is a solution to this that is often used in the industry I just don't know about it. I do not want to release unusable work.

Comment: You could try an app like Instant Meshes to see what it gives on your object: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ISgdREmFO7w

Comment: I will definitely try this now, thank you!

Comment: Here you have a comparison, Quad Remesher is the best according to him, it's a paid app: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CviZw41IbMg but Instant Meshes has a good rating